# XNA - How to open a new window?

Tags: vb.net, xna

How do I open a win forum in XNA?

My code:

```
''' <summary>
''' This is the main type for your game
''' </summary>
Public Class Game1
    Inherits Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game

    Private ATO_Main As New ATO_Main

    Private WithEvents graphics As GraphicsDeviceManager
    Private WithEvents spriteBatch As SpriteBatch

    Public Sub New()
        graphics = New GraphicsDeviceManager(Me)
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content"
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    ''' This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    ''' related content.  Calling MyBase.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    ''' and initialize them as well.
    ''' </summary>
    Protected Overrides Sub Initialize()
        ' TODO: Add your initialization logic here
        MyBase.Initialize()

        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 1024
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 768

        graphics.ApplyChanges()

        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Width
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Height
        graphics.IsFullScreen = True
        graphics.ApplyChanges()

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    ''' all of your content.
    ''' </summary>
    Protected Overrides Sub LoadContent()
        ' Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = New SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice)

        ' TODO: use Me.Content to load your game content here
        ATO_Main.Show()
        ATO_Main.BringToFront()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    ''' all content.
    ''' </summary>
    Protected Overrides Sub UnloadContent()
        ' TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    ''' checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    Protected Overrides Sub Update(ByVal gameTime As GameTime)
        ' Allows the game to exit
        If GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back = ButtonState.Pressed Then
            Me.Exit()
        End If

        ' TODO: Add your update logic here
        MyBase.Update(gameTime)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This is called when the game should draw itself.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    Protected Overrides Sub Draw(ByVal gameTime As GameTime)
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue)

        ' TODO: Add your drawing code here
        MyBase.Draw(gameTime)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: The word is _"form"_ by the way.  2nd question now :P

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out I need this:

```
  ATO_Main = New ATO_Main
    ATO_Main.ShowDialog()
```